# How to declare onPress function with optional input parameter in react native using typescirpt

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am working with `react-native` using `typescript`. I want an onPress method with an **optional** boolean input parameter. And I want to pass it **directly** to the onPress method without creating a new `arrow function` if there is no input. Like below code:

```
const onClose(clearMessages?: boolean) => {
   // doing stuff
   if (clearMessages) {
      // doing extra stuff
   }
}

// use it like this
<Pressable onPress={onClose}>
   <Text>{'Close'}</Text>
</Pressable>

<Pressable onPress={() => onClose(true)}>
   <Text>{'Clear messages'}</Text>
</Pressable>
```

The thing is when I call onClose directly I get the typescript error below:

> Type '(clearMessage?: boolean) => (event: GestureResponderEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: GestureResponderEvent) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'clearMessage' and 'event' are incompatible.
> Type 'GestureResponderEvent' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an expected error! because when you don't call `onClose` function yourself and pass it to `pressable`, then `pressable` expects the function with the below signature

```
((event: GestureResponderEvent) => void)
```

`onPress` passes the parameter which has the type `GestureResponderEvent` and in your `onClose` function you are expecting `boolean`, Hence the error

IMHO this looks clean though

```
onPress={() => onClose()}
```

If you still want it then you can achieve this by using typescript's union type, Just change your `onClose` method like below

```
const onClose = (clearMessages?: GestureResponderEvent | boolean) => {
  // doing stuff
  if (typeof clearMessages === 'boolean') {
    // doing extra stuff
  }
};
```

one more(if you will pass only `true`) then

```
const onClose = (clearMessages?: GestureResponderEvent | true) => {
  // doing stuff
  if (clearMessages === true) {
    // doing extra stuff
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. In the purpose of doing best practices, more readable code, and better performance, which one is better? Calling `onClose` by creating a new arrow function or having an input variable with union type?

Comment: Most of the typescript's code will be removed when compiled to javascript. I prefer readability over performance at least in the above types of cases, Because even If I get any performance benefit there will not be any huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically create a function which return the function you need.

```js
const createFn = (input) => () => { console.log(input); }

const printHelloWorld = createFn("hello");

printHelloWorld();
```

With this in combination of `useCallback()` you can create the onPress function you want in place.

---

Here is a full example on snack.expo.dev =>
https://snack.expo.dev/TPFYRuthi

It's in plain javascript due to the service, but should work in typescript just fine. Just make sure the returned function, with `event` parameter, is the expected `Event` type of `onPress`. ✌️

```js
export default function App() {
  const createOnClose = React.useCallback(
    (clearMessages?: boolean) => (event) => {
      if (clearMessages) {
        console.log('clearing messages');
      }
      console.log('onClose');
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <View>
      <Pressable onPress={createOnClose()}>
        <Text>{'Close'}</Text>
      </Pressable>

      <Pressable onPress={createOnClose(true)}>
        <Text>{'Clear messages'}</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
}
```